# Answer reposted over my objections

Tags: support, deleted-answers, moderation, abuse

I wrote an answer to a question, but later deleted it.

Then a moderator copied the text to my answer and posted it as a community wiki answer. I objected but could not delete it, so I edited the text to indicate that I was removing the text because I objected to the posting. I also flagged it for moderators.

A second moderator reposted it **again**. I **do not want this answer posted**. I **object strongly to having it posted again**. So I edited the same community answer again, removing the text and adding an explanation, because of course I still can't delete this reposting of text I wrote and tried to take back.

As I'm writing this a third moderator has **again** restored the text and locked the post for editing. I don't know what the hell is going on. I want to take this answer back. I keep trying. But for some reason moderators won't let me retract my own answer.

Why can't I delete my own post? I don't want it up. I really, really don't. Please, moderators, how the hell do I get you to just let this go?

[Saving non-English (Hindi, Chinese etc) to SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763607/saving-non-english-hindi-chinese-etc-to-sqlite/54014506#54014506)

Comment: Is it gone now? I don't see a community wiki answer there.

Comment: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/

Comment: Instead of vandalising two answers, wait for a mod to respond to your flag.

Comment: Why do you object to it being posted? If there is a real reason why it should not be here, then you need to explain why, not just repeat that you vaguely object, as the content belongs to the Stack Exchange network, not you.

Comment: Why ragequit over this (after more than 8 years)?

Comment: This message on the users profile-page just made my day: `This account is temporarily suspended to cool down. The suspension period ends in 16 hours.` Did that account in fact overheat or is it a subtle try to bring some sarcasm into messaging?

Comment: @iLuvLogix it's just one of the [boilerplate system messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23385/) that you see when someone is suspended. So unless code has learned to be sarcastic . . .

Comment: @M.A.R.ಠ_ಠ Thx for the link - didn't know that users could be suspended in order to `cool down`.. Still somehow funny that the message refers to the person as 'account' rather than just 'user' ;) Just rechecked - now it changed to `This account is temporarily suspended. The suspension period ends in 14 hours.` The 'account' has `cooled down` enough I guess..

Comment: @DavyM That's false.  The content does *not* belong to Stack Exchange.  It *does* belong to them (unless they haven't told us that the reason they want it deleted is that they don't own it and didn't have the right to apply the CC-SA license to it).  What they have done is *given the public certain rights to the content*, content that *they still own*.  One of those (irrevocable) rights is the right to re-publish it.  That doesn't mean SE owns it, it means that *anyone* has the right to publish it (with certain conditions).  There's a *big* difference between those.

Comment: @Servy It looks like you're right, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 22):

> Then a moderator copied the text to my answer and posted it as a community wiki answer.

That is inaccurate. A "moderator" did not do this; a regular user did.

> I edited the text to indicate that I was removing the text because I objected to the posting.

That's not really allowed. While we generally give some deference to the owner of the post, that isn't *you* in this case. It's not your name at the bottom of the post. You may have provided the original text, but it's not yours anymore.

Now, you can remove your *name* from it. But anything you post on SE sites is licensed to the site via the Creative Common license. Specifically, [CC-BY-SA3](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). Which means that others can use that text, so long as they give attribution.

In short, SE will generally not simply remove your text. Not unless there's private information or something there. In most cases, the best you can do is get answers you own de-associated with your account. But the text is still licensed and on the site. And if someone wants to copy it to their own answer, as long as they abide by the terms of CC-BY-SA3, that's their right.

> A second moderator reposted it again.

When you take an answer and remove all of the content from it, that's called "vandalism". A moderator did not "repost" it; they merely undid your vandalism.